# Can someone explain the difference in Lua from ":" and "." operators?

Tags: lua

I'm coming from Java and I just can't wrap my mind around why I see : and . used in what I would only use . for in Java.

For example I see this in Lua.

`Person.doSomething()` and then I see `Person:GetName()`

and in Java I would have only used the first option to execute a function. Am I just missing something basic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `obj:Method(...)` is literally identical to `obj.Method(obj, ...)`, except that it only evaluates `obj` once.

Similarly, declaring `function obj:Method(...)` is identical to declaring `function obj.Method(self, ...)`.

Basically, `:` is used whenever the function needs to have the concept of `self`.